# Could not load file or assembly HttpException (0x80004005)

Tags: c#, dll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Troubleshooting BadImageFormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996653/troubleshooting-badimageformatexception)

I'm trying to compile my solution and i receive an error about a dll. I've copied that dll in the bin folder in another solution and it does not compile it(the second solution is not related to that dll,it does not use it)

The error I receive is the following error:

```
Server Error in '/browsertest1' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'KT.AF.Engine.Core' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Description: `An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.`

Exception Details: `System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'KT.AF.Engine.Core' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'KT.AF.Engine.Core' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Stack Trace:

```
[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'KT.AF.Engine.Core' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +567
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +192
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +35
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +118

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'KT.AF.Engine.Core' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +11392147
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +484
   System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +127
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +334
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +280
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1087

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'KT.AF.Engine.Core' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11524352
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +141
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4782309

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

Comment: are you compiling as x64/x86 anywhere? are you using com?

Comment: What does HttpException have to do with it?

Comment: Is KT.AF.Engine.Core.dll written in managed code?

Comment: Did you read the [MSDN Article on your error code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx) All the current suggestions are mentioned in the Remarks section.

Comment: KT.AF.Engine.Core.dll is written in managed code. I am compiling as x86.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks the DLL file has been compiled for a different system architecture than what your solution is building at.

Ensure two things:

Your project is set to build to 'Any CPU' - this can be found in Visual Studio's project properties.

IIS has been set up to allow 32-bit applications in your app pool.

Comment: the DLL file has been compiled with visual studio 2010 sp1 under x86. I'm using visual studio 2010 but upgraded to sp1 and still does not work.