# Unable to load dll in windows forms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

When I'm using some `dll` I get the message below:

[image: demo]

This `dll` is working fine on some systems, but I can't get it to work on some others. I can't figure out why. How can I solve this for all systems?

Comment: Honestly you could have typed in that error message rather than posting a photo

Comment: You should provide:  sample code (the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem), the list of systems you've tried and which ones work and which ones don't, other information such as how your code is compiled.

Comment: Tell us more about this dll.  Is it .NET?  Unmanaged?  x86?  x64?  p-invoke?  (I'm betting on the latter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of _[BadImageFormatException C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917204/badimageformatexception-c-sharp)_.   The error is caused by trying to load an **unmanaged** DLL of a different bit-ness to the process (x86/x64)

Answer (score 0):

0x8007007E - that's because you might be using 64 bit dll on 32 bit machine or the other way around.

Comment: Not always, you can use a 32 bit DLL on Windows x64 if the process is also 32 bit. It's generally a problem of different module bit-ness across a process rather than an OS problem.  But yes, entirely wrong deployments of a set of x64 DLLs + x64 EXEs won't work on x86 and vice versa.