# connection error with Sqlite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I want to connect my application with sqlite database but it throw the exception.

> An exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in
>   Scrap_Book.Windows.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

```
        var dbpath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "scrapbook.sqlite");
        using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath))
```

Second line throw exception.

I am unable to resolve it. please help me i am new in programming.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996653/troubleshooting-badimageformatexception

Comment: I install sqlite-net package

Comment: which added two class in my project  Sqlite.cs and SQLiteAsync.cs and exception occurs in SQlite.cs

Comment: A package added .cs files? That's odd. Better check again, and add very precise info about which package you added. There are a lot of similar looking packages for sqlite/uwp .You should probably be using __sqlite-net-pcl__ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I install sqlite-net package.

@Henk was right, you installed a wrong package for UWP app, what you need is [SQLite.Net-PCL](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL) package. And for connection, you can code for example like this:

```
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "scrapbook.sqlite")))
{
    //TODO：
}
```

and don't forget, your project will also need to reference to `SQLite for Universal App Platform`.