# BadImageFormatException when calling zlib1 from Unit Test

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, zlib

I have an odd issue that hopefully someone else has encountered.

- I have a Unit Test (i.e. `TestFileExtract`)
- that calls a method in a class (`Test.Expand.Uncompresss`)
- that makes a call to a referenced DLL
- that makes a call to the ZLIB1.DLL
- to uncompress a file.

Here is the import :

```
[DllImport(ZLIB_NAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

public static extern int uncompress(byte[] dest, ref int dest_len, byte[] src, int src_len);
```

There is an existing console app that loads the 1st Assembly, calls the method that triggers the uncompress with no issues.  However, when I make the exact same call from within my unit test, it fails with `BadImageFormatException`.

I tried setting the test to x64, x86, auto with no success.  I also tried rebuilding the calling assembly to x64/AnyCPU.  Same results.  I'm sure (hoping) it's something I've overlooked.

Any ideas?

Comment: MSDN lists the cases when BadImageFormatException may be invoked: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Maybe look here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996653/troubleshooting-badimageformatexception

Comment: Thx.  I'll take a look to see if any of the SO answers will help.