# Browser' threw an exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException in cefsharp version 49.0.0

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded

Browser' threw an exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException in cefsharp version 49.0.0

```
 === Pre-bind state information ===
        LOG: DisplayName = CefSharp.WinForms, Version=49.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138
         (Fully-specified)
        LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/OZTERN_WORKING/Offline/OzternOffline/OzternOffline/bin/x86/Debug/
        LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
        Calling assembly : OzternOffline, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
        ===
        LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
        LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\OZTERN_WORKING\Offline\OzternOffline\OzternOffline\bin\x86\Debug\OzternOffline.vshost.exe.Config
        LOG: Using host configuration file: 
        LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
        LOG: Post-policy reference: CefSharp.WinForms, Version=49.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138
        LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/OZTERN_WORKING/Offline/OzternOffline/OzternOffline/bin/x86/Debug/CefSharp.WinForms.DLL.
        ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.
```

Comment: You should provide more the code, not just only this error.

Comment: BadImageFormatException can be a sign that 64bits and 32bits assemblies are mixed. It seems like you are working on a x86 specific assembly. Try set it to AnyCPU. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996653/troubleshooting-badimageformatexception?rq=1