# System.BadImageFormatException: after removing Microsoft.SharePoint.Client dll from project

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In a legacy ASP.NET 3.5 WebForms application I added a **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client dll** for **2010 Sharepoint**.

After removing it I can successfully build the project, but when accessing the page I get a **System.BadImageFormatException**.

I have removed all dependencies from the project(project files, config files etc.). Framework is the same it compiles against as before, and platform also.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`BadImageFormatException` usually indicates an attempt to load a 64-bit assembly into a 32-bit environment, or vice versa. See this:

[Troubleshooting BadImageFormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996653/troubleshooting-badimageformatexception)