# BadImageFormatException when running web app on IIS, but all my projects are Any CPU

Tags: asp.net, iis, badimageformatexception

I have an ASP.NET web app I'm trying to run on a local IIS, but when I do so I get a BadImageFormatException. This happens even though all my projects are set to Any CPU. Nothing is wrong with the web app configuration; it runs just fine on my other PC, but on this laptop I get the error.

Comment: Have you been through [Troubleshooting BadImageFormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8996653/1115360)?

Comment: Web application bitness on IIS is controlled by application pool setting, not your project setting.

Comment: @LexLi Oh, that's interesting - I don't have the laptop on me at the moment, but I bet that was it! Next time I need to use the laptop I'll check that out...